# During installation of Ubuntu 19.04 on Acer an515-51-75kz I can move the touchpad, but I can not click on any option

Tags: system-installation, touchpad, synaptics

I own the an515-51-75kz notebook model with the Synaptics touchpad. I'm trying to install Ubuntu 19.04, but I can not select the language options. When I press the `Tab` key, it works for a while, but then the options lock again and I can not complete the installation!

Comment: Do you have a USB mouse ready? Is the notebook very new?

Comment: I will still test with an external usb mouse! I am part of the Acer community and checking in the dashboard, this model began to be distributed on 2018/01/31. So it's a relatively new notebook. This model has an intel hd 630 video card and an nvidia gtx1050ti video card.

Comment: In some cases you might need a newer kernel in others a different driver. I'd suggest finishing the install and then check further.

Comment: I can not finish the installation because I can not click continue!

Comment: Navigating with arrow keys and enter should work.

Answer (score 0):

Launch Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>, searching for "*Terminal*", and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> after it appears. Then run the following command

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click
```

If the output is `false`, then run the following command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true
```